# Loop through an Array to enable checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm have a set of checkboxes and an array that contains the index of which checkboxes should be selected. I'm trying to loop through the array and for each index in it. I made a sample jsFiddle to give you guys an idea of what I'm trying to do. I have the JQuery library also if that makes things easier. http://jsfiddle.net/7EetA/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arrx=new Array();
arrx[0]=4;       
arrx[1]=5;
arrx[2]=3;
arrx[3]=1;
for (var i = 0; i < arrx.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName('cal')[arrx[i]].checked = true;
}
​
```

No jQuery needed! **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7EetA/2/)**

Comment: better to use `.setAttribute('checked',true)` than to use `.checked = true`

Comment: @j08691 DOM objects have an abstraction layer, which is essentially used to hide the internals. using `.checked` you are using an exposed value that might be changed in the future. The setter here is however and abstraction layer, allowing browsers to improve/change the object in the future without breaking your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrx=new Array();
arrx[0]=4;       
arrx[1]=5;
arrx[2]=3;
arrx[3]=1;

var calArray = document.getElementsByName("cal");
for (var i = 0; i < arrx.length; i++) {
    calArray[arrx[i]].checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using jQuery:

```
var arrx=new Array();
arrx[0]=4;       
arrx[1]=5;
arrx[2]=3;
arrx[3]=1;
var i = 0;
$('[name=cal]').each(function() { 
    if ($.inArray(i, arrx) != -1) {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    }
    i++;
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7EetA/7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jQuery, it can do it quite easily based on the name of the input:

jQuery('[name="cal"]').each(function(i){jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');});

If your goal is to not necessarily select all of them, however, you could use something like this:

jQuery('[name$="_c"]').each(function(i){jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');});

which only checks inputs with _c at the end of the name.

http://jsfiddle.net/7EetA/9/