# Loop through an Object array to enable checkboxes

Tags: jquery, spring

I've been searching but I can't find exactly what I need.

My problem is similar to this one:[oop through an Array to enable checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459360/loop-through-an-array-to-enable-checkboxes)

But I don't have a simple var Array. Let's say I have an object Travel with a list of Airports. And I want to edit my Travel. In my jsp I have the complete list of Airports: (I'm using Spring)

```
<c:forEach var="airport" items="${airports}">
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="airportsIds" value="${airport.id}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${airport.name}" /></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Now I want to use jQuery to loop through the list of Airports of my Travel object and check the ones that it already has.

${airports} is the complete list of airports.

The list of airports of Travel would be ${travel.airports}

```
public class Travel {
    private List<Airport> airports;
    ...
}

public class Airport {
    private String Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Country;
    ...
}
```

(Simplified versions of the classes)

And I have a method in my controller with the following:

```
mav.getModelMap().put("travel", travel); //commandObject
List<Airports> airports = getAllAirportsFromDB();
mav.getModelMap().put("airports", airports);
```

Hope I'm being clear enough :)

Comment: what does ${travel.airports} contain ? post sample values.

Comment: As Kabilan says, it depends whether you've output the values of ${travel.airports} in your JSP and in what format, because that affects how jQuery can work with the values.

Comment: Added more code. If you need anything else let me know!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to access all of the checkboxes using the selector `input[name=airportIds]` since all of them have the name of `airportIds`

```
$("input[name=airportIds]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

**EDIT**

---

If you want to loop through the ones that are in the `Travel` object, you will have to have some extra data written on the page, or to some inline JS. Maybe in each  tag set an attr `data-is-in-travel` if the specified airport is part of  `${travel.airports}`

I'm a C# person(so if there are syntax errors, forgive me):

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="airportsIds" value="${airport.id}" 
     data-is-in-travel="${travel.airports.contains(airport)}"/></td>
```

And then in jQuery

```
$("input[data-is-in-travel=true]")
```

Comment: Ok. But I only want to check the ones that travel has. If I understand correctly, that checks all the airports on the list. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Inpired by ShaneA post I ended up creating a list of ids (travel.airports ids) on the controller and passing it to the jsp.

```
List<Long> aiportIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (Airport a : travel.getAirports()) {
    aiportIds.add(a.getId());
}
mav.getModelMap().put("aiportIds", allowed);
```

From there I did:

```
var airportsIds = ${airportsIds};
$.each(airportsIds, function() {
    $("#" + this).attr("checked", "checked");
})
```

Would have preffered to use ${travel.airports} directly on the loop but jQuery didn't like the Airport object.